# How to connect GNS3 to loopback adapter on Windows 10

Tags: ethernet, ipv4, gns3, loopback, windows

I'm trying to have a simple topology by connecting a router (c7200) and the local machine which is windows 10. For this I use GNS3 GUI (not the VM application). I have to do that, due to the limit of the RAM I can't run GNS3 on VM, since even after setting up the topology I have to start Pycharm. I set up loopback adapter and GNS3 router configuration correctly but I couldn't connect them. I turned off the firewall and restarted the PC as well but didn't work out. It's really helpful if anyone can help me on this. GNS3 version is  2.2.15 on Windows (64-bit) with Python 3.6.8 Qt 5.12.1 and PyQt 5.12
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly - a loopback is an internal, virtual interface that you can't connect anything to.

Comment: Yeah since the GNS3 router also an internal device it should be able to connect to the loopback adapter. Matter of fact I have watched videos on it's getting done. It can be done on both GUI & VM applications of GNS3. But when I try it (I use GUI), it doesn't work.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**.On Windows 10 open the Run window and type hdwwiz and click OK. The hdwwiz command is a short way to add and Adapter

**Step 2**. After the hardware wizard opens, click Next to Continue.

**Step 3.** Continue by selecting Advanced as we will add the Loopback card manually.

**Step4.** In the Hardware Types window, select Network Adapters  and click the Next button.

**Step 5.** Select Microsoft from the manufacturer section, and then select Microsoft KM-TEST Adapter from the right pane.

**Step 6**. The following window provides a summary of the hardware to be installed. In this window, click Next to continue.

**Step7.** Adding hardware is complete and click Finish to close the window.

**Step 8.** You can see that the loopback card has added successfully. You can rename the loopback card to avoid confusing it with other network cards.

**Step 9**.Double-clck on GNS3LOOPback.

**Step 10**. You need to set and IP address for the GNS3Loopback network card. You can change the IP address settings here. After configuring the IP address settings. Click OK to save the settings.

**Step 11**. You can check the configuration by clicking the details button on the network card.

**Step12**. After restoring your computer, run the GNS3 program and create a new project.

**Step 13.** Drag and drop one Router and Cloud into the GNS3 workspace. Click Right-Click / Configure to set up Cloud1.

**Step 14**. IN the Cloud1 configuration window, you need to select the loopback network card you added in the Ethernet interfaces section. Once you have selected the GNS3Loopback adapter, click the Add button.

**Step 15**. After successfully completing the loopback network card insertion steps, click OK to save the settings.

**Step 16.** To cable cloud1 and Cisco Router, Chick cabling then click Could1. The Loopback network card will become selectable as you can see in the image below.

**Step 17.** Assign an IP address to the Cisco Router FastEthernet 0/0 interface and turn it on Then, test the connection by pinging the loopback IP address.
Cloud1 and Cisco router can communicate with each other.